load event doesn't fire in iframe when code is broken up with setTimeout
We have an in house js framework that contains JS functions specific to a number of controls that can be used on a page. Some of these controls need js initialising at different points i.e. immediate (in an IIFE), domContentLoaded, and load. This is distributed to multiple projects as a single minified JS file.
During initialisation, it creates lots of long running tasks on the main thread which block the UI.
I'm trying to break those up, so when each "task" is executed, I wrap it in a setTimeout(func, 0).
One of the controls in the framework is a popup which when passed a URL creates markup around an iframe and loads a page (same origin). This iframe page also includes the same framework JS file as it can use the same controls which will need initialising.
In the main window (window.top) this works perfectly, each function runs in its own task and UI is considerably more responsive when loading.
However, if I load a page in the popup iframe, any of those (immediate) functions which need to run a window.load event i.e. to hide a loader, don't fire.
This is how the queue is processed:
When we initialise a control's JS we do so like this:
 _framework.init(NAME, INIT.IMMEDIATE, function () {
     let loader = document.getElementById(ID_LOADER);

     if (loader.classList.contains(CSS_SHOW_BY_DEFAULT)) {
         window.addEventListener("load", hide); // Fires in main window but not iframe
     }
 });

Framework.init gathers the functions it needs to initialising into an object:
_framework.init = function (name, pageLifeCycle, init) {
    if (!name || !pageLifeCycle || !init) {
        throw new Error("name, page life cycle time and init function must be defined");
    }

    let initialiser = {
        [name]: init
    };

    switch (pageLifeCycle) {
        case INIT.IMMEDIATE:
            initialisersImmediate = { ...initialiser, ...initialisersImmediate };
            break;
        case INIT.DOM_CONTENT_LOADED:
            initialisersDOMContentLoaded = { ...initialiser, ...initialisersDOMContentLoaded };
            break;
        case INIT.PAGE_LOAD:
            initialisersPageLoad = { ...initialiser, ...initialisersPageLoad };
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error("invalid init execution time specified");
    }
};

These are then initialised later on:
    function _initialisers(obj) {
        for (const [key, func] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            setTimeout(func, 0);
        }
    };

    _initialisers(initialisersImmediate);

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function domContentLoaded() {
        _initialisers(initialisersDOMContentLoaded);
    });

    window.addEventListener("load", function pageLoad() {
        _initialisers(initialisersPageLoad);
    });

The INIT.IMMEDIATE specifies how it should execute. Only immediate functions are allowed to define events such as load.
If I remove the timeout, everything works fine.
I wondered if someone could shed some light on why this might be happening?

Could you please make it clearer what all the currently undefined functions actually do and from where they're called. Currently it's quite unclear which browsing context window refers to, is it the main page's one or the iframe's? Also, how and when is the iframe actually created and loaded?

Is that any better? To clarify, the iframe is generated using JS in the form of a popup. The page that loads is part of the same site so same origin.
By splitting each control's function using setTimeout prevents the load event in a few controls from firing. But they do fire in window.top (in the main window).

Just a bit better I'm afraid. Does the iframe load the same script on its own context? Does it do it the same way? Does it also have an element with an ID_LOADER id and a CSS_SHOW_BY_DEFAULT class? Do you think you could set up a really minimal example with 1. The minimal markup of the main page. 2. The content of the scripts running on it (just make it log something in the console when expected). 3 The minimal markup of the iframe. 4. The content of the scripts running only there if any.

Thanks, you are right, I'm not sure my edit was clear but I did say "This iframe page also includes the same framework JS file as it can use the same controls which will need initialising."
So you were correct in your assumption. The main page and the iframe page are same origin, and use the same controls and load the same framework JS. It works in the main page just not in the iframe.
I'll try to replicate it. Not sure how I'll do the iframe in a sample on here though.
